# more insights on how PWA works

Tags: google-chrome, web-deployment, user-experience, progressive-web-apps

might be very basic question but just wanted to clear out my doubt, since I'm seeing PWA is like alternative for native application.

**What if browser fail to read/understand manifest file?** 
**what if user is having other/older browser?** (most of the time I see e.g of chrome)
**after installation what are the browser dependencies for PWA?**

Please guide me with the above.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the more important concepts in a PWA is that it is built following the principle of [progressive enhancement](https://alistapart.com/article/understandingprogressiveenhancement), this means that the website would function ordinarily on older browsers (including Safari) and then gain PWA abilities if the user's browser supports them.

Therefore in answer to your three questions:

1. Website would function as normal without the option to "Add to HomeScreen"
2. Same.
3. The PWA runs using the browser, therefore any functionality supported by the browser will be included in your PWA.

Comment: Thanks Kevin.

For #3 - I found one [useful resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915202/what-browser-will-pwa-progressive-web-app-use-after-adding-to-home-screen?answertab=votes#tab-top).