# What browser opens a PWA when it is launched from home screen app icon

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am examining PWA and Web Components technologies recently. As far as I have learned now Web Components is a new suit of tech,
[Custom Elements](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/), [Shadow DOM](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/shadow/), [HTML Templates](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-template-element) and [HTML imports](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/imports/). Together with those Web Components enabling techs [Web App Manifest](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/), [Service Workers](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/), and certain performance improvement techniques used to make what is called as Progressive Web Applications.

What I wonder is when one "Adds to Home Screen" an application in a certain web browser what is the browser that opens it when it is launched from its home screen icon? Is it the browser it has been added to home screen from, or it is the default browser of the system no matter which browser it has been added to home screen from, or it is just a generic web view available on the host operating system at the moment like the one used in native web applications?

Lastly, is it possible for a developer coding her/his app to choose one?

Comment: AFAIK and tried, it's the browser where you click on "add to homescreen". For example on my Android device, if I power up Chrome and tell it to add one site to the homescreen, it opens up with a wrapper of Chrome.

Comment: what about you uninstall the browser you click "add to home screen" and have another browser installed on your device.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, for me, these combinations open a new "Standalone" window
I believe Android/Chrome is the only one that installs a WebApk
All the others are just shortcuts to open your website in that browser without the normal browser navigation items

I know of no options for the developer for how the shortcut opens your PWA

Android 8.10 - Chrome 67
Android 8.10 - Chrome (beta) 68
Android 8.10 - Edge 42
Android 8.10 - Opera 43
iOS 11.4 (simulator) - Safari

Answer (score 0):

As test I created app shortcut of site https://pwa.rocks from browser:

- Brave
- Firefox
- Chrome

and found that there were 3 different shortcut created for each of the browser. Launching each shortcut resulted in opening the respective browser that created it.

I believe there is no way of changing the default browser to launch the app by coding something in the app. I could not find a way of doing that, if someone knows how to do it, I will be interested to know about it

Here is similar question: [What browser will PWA (Progressive Web App) use after adding to home screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915202/what-browser-will-pwa-progressive-web-app-use-after-adding-to-home-screen)